# react.js dynamically grabbing object resulting in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react.js. I have an object literal and I am trying to dynamically select an object within an object based upon what was chosen from a select input. I am getting undefined, however. I have tried both dot and bracket notation. I am successfully grabbing the value of selected option and storing it within a variable. Any ideas?

Here is my object:

```
var horoList = {
aries: {
    title: "JerkFace",
},
cancer: {
    title: "Cancerous",
},
gemini : {
    title: "GoofBall"
}
} ;
```

Here is some of my JSX within the render method:

```
                    <select name="pick-sign" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="aries" >Aries</option>
                        <option value="cancer" >Cancer</option>
                        <option value="gemini" >Gemini</option>
                        <option value="taurus" >Taurus</option>
                    </select>
```

And here is my handle change method:

```
        handleChange: function(e) {
        var selectedHoro = e.target.value;
        console.log(selectedHoro); //outputs: aries
        console.log(horoList); //outputs: Object {aries: Object, cancer: Object, gemini: Object}
        console.log(horoList.aries); //ouputs: Object {title: "JerkFace"}
        console.log(horoList['selectedHoro']); //outputs: undefined
        // this.setState({
        //  horos: horoList.selectedHoro
        // });
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change this line:

`console.log(horoList['selectedHoro']); //outputs: undefined`

To:

`console.log(horoList[selectedHoro]);`

You should get the expected output. When you use `horoList['selectedHoro']`, the literal string value `selectedHoro` is used so it would be `horoList.selectedHoro`. When you use `horoList[selectedHoro]`, `selectedHoro` is a variable and it's value is used to determine the property name you want to resolve so it would resolve to `horoList.aeries` (when `selectedHoro` === `aeries`).